# FFMpeg only uses 4 cores, and underperforms on an Intel 12700K 3600mhz C16 Ram

Tags: ffmpeg, cpu

No matter what job I'm doing, as long as there's transcoding involved, FFMpeg will only use 4 out of my 12 physical cores. Audio, Video, or both - doesn't matter. Arguments? Tried tons of different random combinations, and random files. Same results.

Getting 2-3x less FPS (30-60 video only [libx264], 28-200 audio only [aac]) then on my previous chip, the 2700K (Overclocked) which is insane.

Using a brand new M.2 SAMSUNG 970 EVO Plus (10% full), Intel 12700K, DDR4 3600mhz C16 memory. Core speed is at a stable ~4888mhz at under 40C constantly.

Here's what it looks like - most of the other core usage is from my many other windows open:

[image: Task Manager]

Any idea what could be wrong? I've tried to manually set -threads, no effect. I'm using Windows 10

Comment: `-threads` expects a value, what value are you passing in?

Comment: Full encoding command input properties?

Comment: -threads 0, -threads 8, etc. Tried every combination, no increase in performance. As for encoding command, I just used a bunch of generic stuff like ffmpeg -i input.m4a -codec:a aac output.aac for example. Getting only 30 FPS average on that command. Even using a fast, low quality preset I get poor performance. Really strange!

Comment: Just to re-iterate, this does not happen on my older processor. Maybe there's some issue with the 12000 processors? No clue!

Answer (score 0):

Updating FFMpeg has completely resolved the problem.